# Populating ComboBox inside ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, combobox, wpf-controls

I have populated a `ComboBox` inside a `ListView`. Screen shot is given below
[image]

As shown above it's displaying "M", "a", "c" instead of "Mac". Why it is separating the word into characters?

In code behind file I've written

```
ItemCategoryDAL itemCategoryDalObj = new ItemCategoryDAL();
            DataTable dataTable = itemCategoryDalObj.GetAllItemCategory();

            listView1.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

And in .xaml file I've written:

```
<ListView  Height="148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,12,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="447" >
  <ListView.View>
     <GridView>
        - - - - - - - - 
        - - - - - - - -
        <GridViewColumn Header="Category Name" Width="150">
           <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IC_NAME }" Width="120" />
               </DataTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn> 
        - - - - - - - - -
        - - - - - - - - -
     </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Screen shot of `dataTable` which I used as `ItemSource` for the ListView.(Taken during debuging)
[image]

Answer (score 5):

A `ComboBox` allows the user to select from multiple items.  It populates itself by iterating through all of the items in its `ItemsSource` and adding each item to its `Items`.

You're setting `ItemsSource` to a property that returns a string.  Since a string can be iterated over, the `ComboBox` is populating itself with the items it gets when iterating over it, so the string "Mac" turns into the items "M", "a", and "c".

That's why you're seeing what you're seeing.  The question really is:  what did you expect to see (or what do you want to see) and why?  What items *should* the `ComboBox` be displaying?  If you want it to display all of the category names that appear in the `DataTable`, you could do something like:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=ItemsSource}"
```

and then pull out the `IC_Name` column from each item using a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding IC_Name}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Note that there are going to be all kinds of unexpected phenomena that you encounter by doing this.  For instance, if only one row in the table has "Foo" as a value of `IC_Name`, the moment the user selects some other value for that row and the table gets updated, the value "Foo" will disappear from all of the `ComboBox`es, making it impossible for the user to undo that change.  Also, if five rows contain "Foo", each `ComboBox` will display all five instances of "Foo" in their dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The binding seems to work, IC_NAME exists and returns "Mac" as a string. This will implicitely converted to an enumerable of string with three entries: "M", "a" and "c". And this is then the ItemsSource of your ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IC_NAME }" Width="120" />
```

Probably it should be something like:

```
<ComboBox 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=IC_NAME}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NameOfACollectionProperty }" 
  Width="120" />
```

Comment: `IC_NAME` is a `DataTable` column name.

Comment: @David Webb: IC_NAME returns probably a string. Thats why you see this result. I assume that this is the value you want to be selected in the dropdown and not the ItemsSource. With the ItemsSource, you specify the collection that builds the items.

Comment: Actually what do you mean by `NameOfACollectionProperty`? (may be I don't know it for my lack of knowledge.)

Comment: The items of a combobox must be defined. You can do this either by adding ComboBoxItem-elements in markup or by specifing an ItemsSource. I assume that the IC_NAME-column holds the value that should be selected. This is declared through the SelectedItem or the SelectedValue-property. However if this is the case, you have also to specify which items should be included in the ComboBox. But I have not enough information about your app to say which are the items. Look here for more inform. to ItemsSource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx

Comment: I'm using `dataTable` as `ItemSorce` for the ListView. And using `IC_NAME` column of this DataTable to populate the combobox. In edited version I added the image of `dataTable`

Comment: I'm using the same `DataTable` to populate ComboBox and as `Itemsource` for the ListView. Is this making any problem?