# Loading an array of one item into a WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, listbox

I am experiencing an issue with this code where if item(s) in the array returns less than two strings, the string is display as a list.

For example if I have two clusters. The listbox would give me the option to select let's say Test-Cluster and Dev-Cluster; however, if only Test-Cluster is the only available cluster, the listbox would display each letter of the string as a different option in the list box. I can't seem to figure out why. See picture:

[image]

```bsh
#event: when Environment is selected
$wpFBoxEnvironment.Add_DropDownClosed({
    Disconnect-VIServer * -Confirm:$false
    #empty VCenters inside form 
    $wpFBoxSrcVCenter.Items.Clear()
    $wpFListTgtVCenters.Items.Clear()
    #empty Source VMs inside form 
    $wpFListSrcVMs.Items.Clear()
    #validate VI servers connetion and connect if session doesn't exist
    $VServers = $vdiEnvironments | 
                Where-Object Env -like $wpFBoxEnvironment.Text

    #notify use to wait for vCenter server login
    Write-Host "Logging in to all $($wpFBoxEnvironment.Text) servers. Please wait..."

    foreach ($VServer in $VServers) {
        $sessionID = ($global:DefaultVIServers | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -like $VServer.Name}).sessionId
        if ($sessionID) {
            Connect-VIServer -Server $VServer.Name -Session $sessionID
        } elseif ($credential) {
            Connect-VIServer -Server $VServer.Name -Credential $credential
        } else {
            throw 'Connection Error'
        }
    }

    $clusters = Get-Cluster | Select-Object Name, Uid
    $clusters | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VCName -Value $_.Uid.Split('@')[1].Split(':')[0]
    }

    $datastores = Get-Datastore | Select-Object -Property Name, DatastoreBrowserPath, FreeSpaceMB, CapacityMB
    $datastores | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VCName -Value $_.DatastoreBrowserPath.Split('\')[1].replace('@443','')
        $_.FreeSpaceMB = [int]$_.FreeSpaceMB
        $_.CapacityMB  = [int]$_.CapacityMB
    }

    $portgroups = Get-VDPortgroup | Select-Object VlanConfiguration, Name, NumPorts, Uid | ? VlanConfiguration -notlike "*0-4094*"
    $portgroups | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VCName -Value $_.Uid.Split('@')[1].Split(':')[0]
        $_.NumPorts = [int]$_.NumPorts
    }

    $vCenters = @()
    foreach ($vCenter in $VDIEnvironments) {
        #Find single clusters and padd array
        if (($clusters | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name).Count -eq 1) {
            $clusters += ("-----")
        }
        $vCenter |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetCluster -Value (
                $clusters | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
            )[0].Name -Force
        $vCenter |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Clusters -Value $(
                $clusters | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
            ).Name -Force
        $vCenter |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetDatastore -Value $(
                $datastores | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name | Sort-Object -Descending FreeSpaceMB
            )[0].Name -Force
        $vCenter |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Datastores -Value $(
                $datastores | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
            ).Name -Force 
        $vCenter |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetPortgroup -Value (
                $portgroups | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name | Sort-Object -Descending NumPorts
            )[0].Name -Force
        $vCenter |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Portgroups -Value $(
                $portgroups | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
            ).Name -Force

        $vCenters += $vCenter
    }

    #fill VCenters inside form from selected Environment
    $selectedVCenters = $vCenters | 
        Where-Object Env -like $wpFBoxEnvironment.Text |
        Where-Object Datastores -ne $Null
    $selectedVCenters | ForEach-Object {
        $wpFBoxSrcVCenter.Items.Add($_.Name)
        $wpFListTgtVCenters.Items.Add($_) 
        $wpFListTgtVCenters.SelectedItems.Add($_)
    }
})
```

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Target Cluster" 
                                     Width="160" >
                     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 'Clusters'}"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path='TargetCluster', Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     Width="145"
                            />
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are iterating over either an array, or in the case of a single item, a string. Try predefining your array then add (`+=`) to it. That way in the case of a single string it will still be an array:

Edit:

Looking at the data, it looks like you may have to explicitly convert the single string to an array by wrapping `$_` in `@(..)` to get: `@($_)`

This will either convert the string into a single value array, or keep the existing array. More info: [about_arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6)

```
...
#fill VCenters inside form from selected Environment

$selectedVCenters = @()
$selectedVCenters += $vCenters | 
   Where-Object Env -like $wpFBoxEnvironment.Text | 
   Where-Object Datastores -ne $Null
$selectedVCenters | ForEach-object {
   $wpFBoxSrcVCenter.Items.Add($_.Name)
   $wpFListTgtVCenters.Items.Add(@($_)) 
   $wpFListTgtVCenters.SelectedItems.Add($_)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not seem to make a different. See a picture of the issue. https://ibb.co/qrZ1Dyn

Comment: Can you give a sample output of `$selectedVCenters` one that works/doesn't. The data object is a little confusing. In the `$wpFBoxSrcVCenter.Items.Add($_.Name)` you reference the `$_.Name` Property but then in `$wpFListTgtVCenters.Items.Add($_) ` are you meaning to try and pass the whole object, or a Name?

Comment: Please see picture: https://ibb.co/LhCDNWy
I am passing the whole object. Which works as you can see in the picture above; except where there is only one object returned like Clusters. Datastores and Portgroups are fine.

Comment: Try explicitly defining the variable as an array with `@($_)`. See Edits above

Comment: No luck unfortunately.

Comment: after much reading on the issue it think i found where the issue lies but do not quite sure how to fix it. I believe it is with the WFP XAML comboBox Itemsource. Probably 

I found two posts of others having the same issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089843/populating-combobox-inside-listview-in-wpf